# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

Tags: image, tuples, python-imaging-library

I am trying to train a DQNAgent on Atari Breakout Game for my academic course project. I have trouble with the fit function throwing this error message AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'. Can any one let me know how I should proceed to resolve this issue. I have posted the code below along with the error. You can try running the code in jupyter notebook. Thank you.

```
env = gym.make("BreakoutDeterministic-v4")
nb_actions = env.action_space.n

IMG_SHAPE = (84, 84)
WINDOW_LENGTH = 4
```

```
class ImageProcessor(Processor):
    def process_observation(self, observation):
        img = Image.fromarray(observation)
        img = img.resize(IMG_SHAPE)
        img = img.convert("L")
        img = np.array(img)
        return img.astype('uint8')  # saves storage in experience memory
    
    def process_state_batch(self, batch):

        processed_batch = batch.astype('float32') / 255.
        return processed_batch

    def process_reward(self, reward):
        return np.clip(reward, -1., 1.)
```

```
input_shape = (WINDOW_LENGTH, IMG_SHAPE[0], IMG_SHAPE[1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Permute((2, 3, 1), input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (8, 8), strides=(4, 4),kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())
```

```
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=1000000, window_length=WINDOW_LENGTH)
processor = ImageProcessor()
policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=1., value_min=.1, value_test=.05, nb_steps=1000000)
```

```
pip install keras-rl2==1.0.4

dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy, memory=memory,
               processor=processor, nb_steps_warmup=50000, gamma=.99, target_model_update=10000,
              train_interval=4, delta_clip=1)
```

```
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.00025), metrics=['mae'])

weights_filename = 'dqn_breakout_weights.h5f'
checkpoint_weights_filename = 'dqn_' + "BreakoutDeterministic-v4" + '_weights_{step}.h5f'
checkpoint_callback = ModelIntervalCheckpoint(checkpoint_weights_filename, interval=100000)

model.load_weights("weights/dqn_BreakoutDeterministic-v4_weights_900000.h5f")

policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=0.3, value_min=.1, value_test=.05, nb_steps=100000)

dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy, memory=memory,
               processor=processor, nb_steps_warmup=50000, gamma=.99, target_model_update=10000)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.00025), metrics=['mae'])

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback], log_interval=10000, visualize=False)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 15
     12 dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.00025), metrics=['mae'])
     14 # And train the model
---> 15 dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback], log_interval=10000, visualize=False)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/core.py:134, in Agent.fit(self, env, nb_steps, action_repetition, callbacks, verbose, visualize, nb_max_start_steps, start_step_policy, log_interval, nb_max_episode_steps)
    132 observation = deepcopy(env.reset())
    133 if self.processor is not None:
--> 134     observation = self.processor.process_observation(observation)
    135 assert observation is not None
    137 # Perform random starts at beginning of episode and do not record them into the experience.
    138 # This slightly changes the start position between games.

Cell In[4], line 4, in ImageProcessor.process_observation(self, observation)
      2 def process_observation(self, observation):
      3     # First convert the numpy array to a PIL Image
----> 4     img = Image.fromarray(observation)
      5     # Then resize the image
      6     img = img.resize(IMG_SHAPE)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:2803, in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2764 def fromarray(obj, mode=None):
   2765     """
   2766     Creates an image memory from an object exporting the array interface
   2767     (using the buffer protocol).
   (...)
   2801     .. versionadded:: 1.1.6
   2802     """
-> 2803     arr = obj.__array_interface__
   2804     shape = arr["shape"]
   2805     ndim = len(shape)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I might not have a solution (Edit: I have one now), but I do have and explanation:

`env.reset()` used to return only an array as the observation. But there was a [discussion](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1683) to change the reset function to return the observation AND info. Finally in version [v0.25](https://gymnasium.farama.org/content/migration-guide/#environment-reset) they implement it so now it always returns a tuple, breaking a lot of code like `rl.agents.DQNAgent.fit()` where `env.reset` is still l expected to return only observation

I was facing the same issue so a temporal solution would be editing rl.core.Agent.fit() yourself.

If you're working with a python virtual env, go to `lib\site-packages\rl\core.py`, if you installed global in your system then go to `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXXX\lib\site-packages...`
And in `Agent.fit()` use find and replace with every instance of `observation = deepcopy(env.reset())` and replace it with `observation, info = deepcopy(env.reset())` and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).